# php docker how to use file_get_contents to fetch self domain's result

Tags: php, docker, file-get-contents

I have a project need to server migration, the new server deployed by docker. but in docker, the `file_get_contents()` cannot fetch the result from self domain. and I can't use others way (for example `reqire_once`) to load this file ( this project is too old and code is... you know ).

code:

```
$json = file_get_content("http://this.site.com/xxx/yyy/get_result.php?params=xxx&params2=yyy")
```

If I use it, will get a warning `connect refuese`, if I replace the domain to `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`, will get the same warning, or replace to `http://nginx` ( nginx is another container's name ) will get content, but not my site's content ( it will get contents the same by using 127.0.0.1 in the broswer, not using http://this.site.com )

So it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running with a docker on another instance so is 127.0.0.1 address is different from your computer's address.
You must enter the external IP address of the container

Answer (score 0):

Try using `host.docker.internal`...